# cakephp problemme with download

Tags: cakephp, download

i am working with cakephp, i wrote this code to download a file:

[image]

but when i click to download a file,

[image]

in other words insted of giving me:

```
/public_html/uploads/contracts/téléchargement (3).jpg
```

it gives me :

```
-public_html-uploads-contracts-téléchargement (3).jpg
```

i don't know he's replacing `/` with `-`.

Comment: can anyone help me, i'm really blocked

Comment: Please don't post code as images, but as actual text formatted as code - thanks!

Comment: i don't know why he's replacing "/" with "-", but i used this code and it worked:
if(file_exists(ROOT.'/public_html/uploads/contracts/'.$name)){
            $path = ROOT."/public_html/uploads/contracts/";
            $this->response->file('./public_html/uploads/contracts/'.$name,
                array('download' => true)
            );
            return $this->response;
        }else{
            dd('ff');
            return false;
        }